# Deserializing an xml file into an object

Tags: c#

I'm working in within a windows service I created.  Code works fine on my dev box but when I deploy the code to a server it's not able to find the xml file to deserialize.  The xml files are created in C:\ProgramData\AppName\Filequeue

In the object I created a helper method:

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(input))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

I then create an object using an impersonating object and attempt to read the file:

```
 using (var impersonation = new ImpersonatedUser(AdminName, Domain, ADPass))
 {    
    oMailer = (MailQueue) oMailer.Deserialize<MailQueue>(szFileName);
 }
```

I get a file name not found error when it tries to load the file into the object in the Deserialize() object.  I'm guessing the impersonation isn't flowing into the object that I'm attempting to load.

If I try to load in a text reader under the impersonation I can see the file just fine.  So I know the file exists and is seen by the program.

Anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you show how you build the `szFileName` path?

Comment: There is no building; it's hard coded to "C:\ProgramData\AppName\Filequeue\Test.xml"

I've also tried dropping the C: off the file name as well to specific a relative path.

Comment: If it's throwing `file not found`, it might be helpful to add some logging around the call to the extension method and output the value for `szFileName` perhaps the path is invalid. What does the exception show?

Comment: The path isn't invalid...  As I mentioned above, I can add in a file reader under the deserialize in the same method that contains the impersonation and it loads the file.

Comment: Could you please provide the full exception and stack trace? A `file not found` error is pretty clear, yet you say the file definitely exists. Something is not right.

Comment: While I cannot explain the File not found and having the debug info would help. XmlReader.Create(string) expects an `inputUri` as a path, so you would have to specify something like `file://<your path>` to make it work. Also, in sucha a case you would want to control the `XmlUrlResolver` object creation yourself to control the credential it uses for accessing the file.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  It runs great on my dev box.  It just doesn't work when I deploy it to a server.

Comment: 'deploy to server' - now that's something new. So you are saying the above code works as is in your box and not when deployed? If that is the case and assuming you are getting File Not Found on server deployed code, then it looks like a permission issue to the account running the service or the path itself on the server does not exists?

Comment: That's exactly what it was, a permission issue.  For some reason the impersonation code wasn't following down into the newly created object within that method.  See the answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the file reader code to under the method containing impersonation.  Then created a stand along object:

```
public class Serializer
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    public string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I was able to load the XML then load and deserialize it by:

```
using (impersonation...)
{
   var reader = File.ReadAllText(szFileName);
   oMailer =  ser.Deserialize<MailQueue>(reader);
}
```

I'm still confused on why the impersonation doesn't seem to inherit into an object that is created within the impersonation?  But I don't have time to deal with that now...

Comment: Can you not move the `using( impersonation` code into your Serializer since it seems like you would always end up doing it for all your file reads? So basically, you calling code will be `oMailer = (MailQueue) oMailer.Deserialize<MailQueue>(szFileName);` and the `using` statement of impersonation sits inside your deserialize method?

Comment: No, I wish I could... I put it at the top method.  I can't add it to the object without reworking how security works between the classes.